Is presentism compatible with modern physics?
When considering an essay under the title "Critically assess presentism", it strikes me presentism's heaviest criticism comes from our understanding of physics -- especially relativity. Where exactly does the conflict originate? Can either presentism or the conflicting physics theories be adapted from their orthodox forms to be more compatible? Can anybody provide a viable defence of presentism considering such strong implications of eternalism in modern physics?

Presentism has metaphysical problems aside from modern physics, but it does come into direct conflict with relativity because of positing absolute simultaneity which is non-existent on its standard interpretation. One can adapt Lorentz's ether to get an absolute frame in special relativity, but this is seen as contrived because it is unobservable in principle, and it is unclear how to extend it to general relativity, see SEP, Presentism.

Yes, you can adapt presentism by dropping the assumption of an absolute universal present and instead confining your interpretation of now, like here, to be a local matter.

If one just considers what is co-present to oneself (or one's approximate centre), with time dilation calculations and oneself as the stationary point, one could map out a range of locations (e.g. twins on spaceships) and coordinate a common moment, but only simultaneous to oneself. If the calculations are done with respect to a different stationary point the time-dilation clock adjustment become different. That's how presentism rolls out using physics. It exists, just it's rather limited.

Time dilation applies to the moving object. E.g. in the twin paradox the twin who stays on Earth is considered stationary since does not experience the acceleration of the other twin's rocket. So the moving twin's time is slowed.

Please do not upvote. I voted to close the question but I wanted to give some more references that are helpful and not mentioned in the related question.
Relevant to this question is I think the Rietdijk-Putnam argument and the Andromeda paradox mentioned in that article.
Arguments for presentism and to show that the Andromeda paradox is not the be all and end all of this question in this blogpost by Sabine Hossenfelder.

From your second link, “if everything exists that Bob calls simultaneous” – what exists is what is ‘present-at-hand’ for Bob, which can be merely in mind, such as Bob’s twin zooming off into deep space in a rocket. Personal presentism is what it is.

The thought of "the present" is indeed an old one. You can't dip your toes in the same river twice.
